# Creating a Android Service that pulls user data via XML

Tags: android, xml, json, http, rest

I want to create a android app service that allows users to have their own profiles they sign into that are stored on a database. I realize the login part is a whole nother can of worms, but as far as the dynamic data goes...aka parsing xml/json aka 500 million different ways to do it aka extremely confusing for someone fairly new to know what to spend their time focusing in on and learning.... what is the proven chain of events for doing this?

I been working really really hard to figure this all out and im going to try to not make this to broad to avoid being flammed ,every thread i see about this does.yet i have yet to find one thread or tutorial that says outright "look, there are a outrageous amount of different ways of creating a android member based service, but heres one that accepted by the industry as a fairly efficient way of getting it done.  From a really broad point of view ur gonna need xyz type of database.look into these..., ur gonna need xyz php or rub server side client,i suggest starting with php and looking up tutorials on the following php keywords..., and finally ur gonna use [insert parsing library, be it REST, SAX, DOM w.e it is] and ur gonna need to be familiar with xyz java concepts first."

Yeah , ik there are a million ways to do it , everyone's different its based on preference, but before you say that to me think back to when you were in my shoes. What i need right now more than anything is a guiding light so my efforts arnt wasted spending weeks learning about stuff that doesnt fit together.Give me a big picture of how you would plan the formspring app if you and ur team were assigned to build it tomorrow. I dont need the best way of doing things, i just need a way that the avg developer would agree will get the job done semi efficiently. This is just as valid/good of a question as anything else.

Comment: idk what that is? are you trying to say toddler?

Comment: Your question looks like a rant, so at the bottom of your question, sum it up

Comment: To sum it up I want a few different rough descriptions of android services,start to finish that allows users to interact/have profiles. 

I had to say what I said because if you look around here anyone who asks this around here usually gets flammed on/voted down bc alot of programmers have been doing this stuff so long they've lost touch with what its like to be new and on ur own with no peers to turn to for help.What most developers believe is "common sense" almost always is not. You all have a existing base of knowledge that builds on everything following, that you all constantly undermine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am developing pretty much same application. I am also kinda new to android (developing for 3 months) so here is the thing I picked up.

The login i use unsecure login & pass saved on shared prefrences on android and i log in only into the aplication it self (no login on data server). As i can have many users I decided to get "unique ID" *Android device UUID is unique only on 99,9% . Then connecting to database and sending as "login"/paramater this ID. I use web application written in .NET and to communicati with it on android I use ksoap2 for consuming web services. My web service returns xml file so i just parse it and that's it.

Not the best way propably one of the worst but there is a plenty of tutorials on how to use ksoap 2 for android with parameters or even complex objects.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, this is a start. I of course encourage more answers, but its a step in the right direction. I really wish someone would make a "Dynamic App blueprint" blog post that shows graphically a few different blueprints for creating a android service. If no one makes it before I get good enough I will make it myself.